# Problem with write.csv() and as.data.frame()

Tags: r, dataframe, error-handling, sparse-matrix

I’m trying to save my matrix to a file, but a get an error:
`“Error in command 'as.data.frame.default(A)': cannot convert class 'structure("dsCMatrix", package = "Matrix")' to class "data.frame"”`

I know I cannot use the matrix in `write.csv()` function but I have a problem converting the matrix into a data frame. Can anyone give me some tips

Comment: Can you try converting with `as.data.frame.matrix(yourmatrix)`

Answer (score 3):

We may convert to `data.frame` after converting to regular matrix

```
write.csv(as.data.frame.matrix(mat), "file.csv")
```